# How to prevent the Kendo grid from loading the data twice if endless scrolling is enabled?

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, grid, kendo-grid

I have a Kendo grid with server side paging/sorting/filtering and with endless scrolling enabled. With this scenario I have the problem that when the grid is filtered, the data is loaded twice. The first time all data is loaded and the second time the filtered data is loaded.

To reproduce the problem you have to do the following steps.

Code Example: https://dojo.telerik.com/@Ruben/OnODErav

1. Scroll down in the grid until new data is loaded
2. In the console there should be the event "Grid data bound" two times by now
3. Set any filter on any column
4. Now you have the event "Grid data bound" four times in the console, instead of three times!

The error occurs only after you scrolled down. If you restart and only do step three you will see that the event is only fired two times (initial one and after filtering) which is correct.

Does anybody know how I can prevent it from loading the data twice?

```js
   function onDataBound(arg) {
                    kendoConsole.log("Grid data bound");
                }
              
                $(document).ready(function() {
                    $("#grid").kendoGrid({
                        dataSource: {
                            type: "odata",
                            transport: {
                                read: "https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/Northwind.svc/Orders"
                            },
                            schema: {
                                model: {
                                    fields: {
                                        OrderID: { type: "number" },
                                        Freight: { type: "number" },
                                        ShipName: { type: "string" },
                                        OrderDate: { type: "date" },
                                        ShipCity: { type: "string" }
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            pageSize: 20,
                            serverPaging: true,
                            serverFiltering: true,
                            serverSorting: true
                        },
                        height: 550,
                        dataBound: onDataBound,
                        filterable: true,
                        sortable: true,
                        scrollable: {
                            endless: true
                        },
                        pageable: {
                            numeric: false,
                            previousNext: false
                        },
                        columns: [{
                                field:"OrderID",
                                filterable: false
                            },
                            "Freight",
                            {
                                field: "OrderDate",
                                title: "Order Date",
                                format: "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}"
                            }, {
                                field: "ShipName",
                                title: "Ship Name"
                            }, {
                                field: "ShipCity",
                                title: "Ship City"
                            }
                        ]
                    });
                });
                
                 (function($, undefined){
    window.kendoConsole = {
        log: function(message, isError, container) {
            var lastContainer = $(".console div:first", container),
                counter = lastContainer.find(".count").detach(),
                lastMessage = lastContainer.text(),
                count = 1 * (counter.text() || 1);

            lastContainer.append(counter);

            if (!lastContainer.length || message !== lastMessage) {
                $("<div" + (isError ? " class='error'" : "") + "/>")
                    .css({
                        marginTop: -24,
                        backgroundColor: isError ? "#ffbbbb" : "#b2ebf2"
                    })
                    .html(message)
                    .prependTo($(".console", container))
                    .animate({ marginTop: 0 }, 300)
                    .animate({ backgroundColor: isError ? "#ffdddd" : "#ffffff" }, 800);
            } else {
                count++;

                if (counter.length) {
                    counter.html(count);
                } else {
                    lastContainer.html(lastMessage)
                        .append("<span class='count'>" + count + "</span>");
                }
            }
        },

        error: function(message) {
            this.log(message, true);
        }
    };
})(jQuery);

/*
 * jQuery Color Animations
 * Copyright 2007 John Resig
 * Released under the MIT and GPL licenses.
 */

(function(jQuery) {

    // We override the animation for all of these color styles
    jQuery.each(["backgroundColor", "borderBottomColor", "borderLeftColor", "borderRightColor", "borderTopColor", "color", "outlineColor"], function(i, attr) {
        jQuery.fx.step[attr] = function(fx) {
            if (!fx.state || typeof fx.end == typeof "") {
                fx.start = getColor(fx.elem, attr);
                fx.end = getRGB(fx.end);
            }

            fx.elem.style[attr] = ["rgb(", [
                Math.max(Math.min(parseInt((fx.pos * (fx.end[0] - fx.start[0])) + fx.start[0], 10), 255), 0),
                Math.max(Math.min(parseInt((fx.pos * (fx.end[1] - fx.start[1])) + fx.start[1], 10), 255), 0),
                Math.max(Math.min(parseInt((fx.pos * (fx.end[2] - fx.start[2])) + fx.start[2], 10), 255), 0)
            ].join(","), ")"].join("");
        };
    });

    // Color Conversion functions from highlightFade
    // By Blair Mitchelmore
    // http://jquery.offput.ca/highlightFade/

    // Parse strings looking for color tuples [255,255,255]
    function getRGB(color) {
        var result;

        // Check if we're already dealing with an array of colors
        if (color && color.constructor == Array && color.length == 3) {
            return color;
        }

        // Look for rgb(num,num,num)
        result = /rgb\(\s*([0-9]{1,3})\s*,\s*([0-9]{1,3})\s*,\s*([0-9]{1,3})\s*\)/.exec(color);
        if (result) {
            return [parseInt(result[1], 10), parseInt(result[2], 10), parseInt(result[3], 10)];
        }

        // Look for #a0b1c2
        result = /#([a-fA-F0-9]{2})([a-fA-F0-9]{2})([a-fA-F0-9]{2})/.exec(color);
        if (result) {
            return [parseInt(result[1], 16), parseInt(result[2], 16), parseInt(result[3], 16)];
        }

        // Otherwise, we're most likely dealing with a named color
        return jQuery.trim(color).toLowerCase();
    }

    function getColor(elem, attr) {
        var color;

        do {
            color = jQuery.css(elem, attr);

            // Keep going until we find an element that has color, or we hit the body
            if (color && color != "transparent" || jQuery.nodeName(elem, "body")) {
                break;
            }

            attr = "backgroundColor";

            elem = elem.parentNode;
        } while (elem);

        return getRGB(color);
    }

    var href = window.location.href;
    if (href.indexOf("culture") > -1) {
        $("#culture").val(href.replace(/(.*)culture=([^&]*)/, "$2"));
    }

    function onlocalizationchange() {
        var value = $(this).val();
        var href = window.location.href;
        if (href.indexOf("culture") > -1) {
            href = href.replace(/culture=([^&]*)/, "culture=" + value);
        } else {
            href += href.indexOf("?") > -1 ? "&culture=" + value : "?culture=" + value;
        }
        window.location.href = href;
    }

    $("#culture").change(onlocalizationchange);
})(jQuery);
```

```css
/*global*/

.floatWrap:after,#example:after{content:"";display:block;clear:both}
.floatWrap,#example{display:inline-block}
.floatWrap,#example{display:block}
.clear{clear:both}

body,h1,h2,h3,h4,p,ul,li,a,button
{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    list-style:none;
}

html
{
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    overflow-y:scroll;
    font:75% Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    background: #f5f7f8;
}
body
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

a,
li>a,
h2>a,
h3>a,
a
{
    text-decoration:none;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
}

a
{
    color: #0487c4;
}

a:hover
{
    text-decoration: underline;
}

.page
{
    max-width:72%;
    margin: 2% auto;
    padding: 3% 5% 0;
    background: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #e2e4e7;
}

.offline-button {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 0 30px;
    padding: 9px 23px;
    background-color: #015991;
    border-radius: 2px;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: 700;
    line-height: 1.2;
    transition-duration: 0.2s;
    transition-property: background-color;
    transition-timing-function: ease;
}

.offline-button:hover {
    background-color: #013a5e;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#example
{
    margin: 2em 0 5em;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    background: transparent;
    font-size: 14px;
}

/*console*/

.console
{
    background-color: transparent;
    color: #333;
    font: 11px Consolas, Monaco, "Bitstream Vera Sans Mono", "Courier New", Courier, monospace;
    margin: 0;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    text-align: left;
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid rgba(20,53,80,0.1);
    background-color: #ffffff;
    text-indent: 0;
}

.demo-section .box-col .console
{
    min-width: 200px;
}

.console .count
{
    background-color: #26c6da;
    -moz-border-radius: 15px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 10px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    padding: 2px 6px 2px 5px;
}

.console div
{
    background-position: 6px -95px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #DDD;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    height: 2em;
    line-height: 2em;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.console .error
{
    background-position: 6px -135px;
}

/*configurator*/

.centerWrap .configuration,
.configuration,
.configuration-horizontal
{
    margin: 4.5em auto;
    padding: 3em;
    background-color: rgba(20,53,80,0.038);
    border: 1px solid rgba(20,53,80,0.05);
}

.absConf .configuration
{
    position: absolute;
    top: -1px;
    right: -1px;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0;
    z-index: 2;
}

.configuration-horizontal
{
    position: static;
    height: auto;
    min-height: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    zoom: 1;
}

.configuration-horizontal-bottom
{
    margin: 20px -21px -21px;
    position: static;
    height: auto;
    min-height: 0;
    width: auto;
    float:none;
}

.configuration .configHead,
.configuration .infoHead,
.configuration-horizontal .configHead,
.configuration-horizontal .infoHead
{
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 1em;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}


.configuration .configTitle,
.configuration-horizontal .configTitle
{
    font-size: 12px;
    display: block;
    line-height: 22px;
}

.configuration .options,
.configuration-horizontal .options
{
    list-style:none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.configuration button,
.configuration-horizontal button
{
    margin: 0;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.configuration .k-textbox,
.configuration-horizontal .k-textbox
{
    margin-left: 7px;
    width: 30px;
}

.configuration .options li { display: block; margin: 0; padding: 0.2em 0; zoom: 1; }

.configuration .options li:after,
.configuration-horizontal:after
{
    content: "";
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    height: 0;
}

.configuration-horizontal .config-section
{
    display: block;
    float: left;
    min-width: 200px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px 20px 10px 10px;
}

.configuration label,
.configuration input
{
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: 20px;
    margin-top: 0;
}

.configuration label
{
    float: left;
}

.configuration input
{
    width: 40px;
}

.configuration input,
.configuration select,
.configuration .k-numerictextbox
{
    float: right;
}

.configuration input.k-input
{
    float: none;
}

.configuration .k-button,
.configuration .k-widget
{
    margin-bottom: 3px;
}

/* Code Viewer */
.source {
    background-color: #f5f7f8;
    margin: 0 0 5em;
    border: 1px solid rgba(20,53,80,0.05);
}
.source .code {
    background-color: #fff;
    border-top: 1px solid rgba(20,53,80,0.08);
    padding: 20px 0 0;
}
.source .code pre {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 20px 20px;
}
.source .offline-button {
    background: none;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #0487c4;
    margin: 10px 0 10px 14px;
    padding: 10px;
}

.source .offline-button.selected {
    color: #000;
}

.source .code .controller {
    display: none;
}

/* Pretty Print */
.prettyprint
{
    font-size: 12px;
    overflow: auto;
}

pre .nocode { background-color: transparent; color: #000; }
pre .str,                    /* string */
pre .atv { color: #2db245; } /* attribute value */
pre .kwd { color: #ff3399; } /* keyword */
pre .com { color: #9933cc; } /* comment */
pre .typ { color: #000; } /* type */
pre .lit { color: #0099ff; } /* literal */
pre .pun { color: #333; }    /* punctuation */
pre .pln { color: #3e526b; }    /* plaintext */
pre .tag { color: #3e526b; } /* html/xml tag */
pre .atn { color: #3e526b; } /* attribute name */
pre .dec { color: #3e526b; } /* decimal */

/* Specify class=linenums on a pre to get line numbering */
ol.linenums { margin-top: 0; margin-bottom: 0; color: #333; }
li.L0,li.L1,li.L2,li.L3,li.L5,li.L6,li.L7,li.L8 { list-style-type: none }
li.L1,li.L3,li.L5,li.L7,li.L9 { background: #eee; }

/*keyboard navigation legend */
.key-button {
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #555;
    min-width: 20px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 3px 5px;
    font-size: 12px;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 2px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
    -moz-border-radius: 2px;
    background: #eee;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.1), 0 2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}
.widest {}
.wider {}
.wide {}
.leftAlign, .rightAlign, .centerAlign {text-align: left;}

.letter {
    padding-top: 14px;
    padding-bottom: 11px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 17px;
}

ul.keyboard-legend {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: left;
}

#example ul.keyboard-legend li,
.demo-section .box-col ul.keyboard-legend li {
    display: block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 4px 0;
    line-height: 1.5em;
}

ul.keyboard-legend li a {
    color: #0487C4;
}


.button-preview {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    padding: 0 5px 0 0;
}
.button-descr {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 3px 0;
}

.demo-section p a.hyperlink,
.config-section a {
    color: #e15613;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.chart-wrapper,
.map-wrapper,
.diagram-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    height: 430px;
    margin: 0 auto 15px auto;
    padding: 10px;
}

#example.absConf .chart-wrapper,
#example.absConf .map-wrapper,
#example.absConf .diagram-wrapper
{
    margin-left: 0;
}

.chart-wrapper .k-chart,
.map-wrapper .k-map,
.diagram-wrapper .k-diagram {
    height: 430px;
}

.config-section.console-section
{
    width: 400px;
    float: right;
}

#page > h2 {
    float: none;
    text-align: center;
    width: auto;
    padding: 5em 0 1em;
    font-size: 3em;
}

#suites .imgPlate,
#suites .box {
    border-width: 0;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    -moz-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
}

#suites {
    text-align: center;
}

#suites .box {
    float: none;
    clear: none;
    display: inline-block;
    width: auto;
    min-width: auto;
}

#suites .box h2 {
    margin-top: 1em;
}

#draggable
{
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    top: 210px;
    left: 30px;
    border: 1px solid #ff8000;
    width: 78px;
    height: 78px;
    border-radius: 37px;
    box-shadow: 2px 0 10px #9d9d9d;
    background: #ffcc00 url(../../web/dragdrop/draggable.png) 50% 50% no-repeat;
    background: url(../../web/dragdrop/draggable.png) 50% 50% no-repeat, -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ffcc00 0%, #ff8000 100%);
    background: url(../../web/dragdrop/draggable.png) 50% 50% no-repeat, -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#ffcc00), color-stop(100%,#ff8000));
    background: url(../../web/dragdrop/draggable.png) 50% 50% no-repeat, -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ffcc00 0%,#ff8000 100%);
    background: url(../../web/dragdrop/draggable.png) 50% 50% no-repeat, -o-linear-gradient(top, #ffcc00 0%,#ff8000 100%);
    background: url(../../web/dragdrop/draggable.png) 50% 50% no-repeat, -ms-linear-gradient(top, #ffcc00 0%,#ff8000 100%);
    background: url(../../web/dragdrop/draggable.png) 50% 50% no-repeat, linear-gradient(top, #ffcc00 0%,#ff8000 100%);
}

#draggable.hollow
{
    cursor: default;
    background: #ececec;
    border-color: #cbcbcb;
}

/* Box Styles */

.box {
    margin: 4.5em 7.5em;
    padding: 3em;
    background-color: rgba(20,53,80,0.038);
    border: 1px solid rgba(20,53,80,0.05);
}

.demo-section {
    margin: 0 auto 4.5em;
    padding: 3em;
    border: 1px solid rgba(20,53,80,0.14);
}

.demo-section:not(.wide),
#example .box:not(.wide) {
    max-width: 400px;
}

.box:after,
.demo-section:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    height: 0;
}

#example .box {
    margin: 4.5em auto;
}

#example .box:first-child {
    margin-top: 0;
}

.demo-section.k-content {
    box-shadow: 0 1px 2px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.08), 0 3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,.08);
}

.box h4,
.demo-section h4 {
    margin-bottom: 1em;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 1em;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.box-col {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    padding: 0 3em 1.667em 0;
}

.box ul:not(.km-widget) li,
.demo-section .box-col ul:not(.km-widget) li {
    line-height: 3em;
}

.box li:last-child {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

.box li a {
    font-size: 13px;
}

.box .k-widget {
    background-color: #ebeef0;
    border-color: #ccc;
    color: #7c7c7c;
}
.box .k-widget.k-slider {
    background-color: transparent;
}

.box .k-button {
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 2px;
    font-size: inherit;
    color: #333;
    background: #e2e4e7;
    border-color: #e2e4e7;
    min-width: 90px;
    box-shadow: none;
}

.box .k-upload-status .k-button-bare {
    min-width: 0;
}

.box .k-button:hover,
.box .k-button:focus:active:not(.k-state-disabled):not([disabled]),
.box .k-button:focus:not(.k-state-disabled):not([disabled]) {
    background: #cad0d6;
    border-color: #cad0d6;
    color: #000;
    box-shadow: none;
}

.box .k-primary {
    color: #fff;
    background: #015991;
    border-color: #015991;
}

.box .k-primary:hover,
.box .k-primary:focus:active:not(.k-state-disabled):not([disabled]),
.box .k-primary:focus:not(.k-state-disabled):not([disabled]) {
    background: #013A5E;
    border-color: #013A5E;
    color: #fff;
}

.box .k-textbox,
.box textarea {
    background: #fff;
    border-color: #e2e4e7;
    color: #555;
    border-radius: 2px;
}

.box .k-textbox:hover,
.box .k-textbox:active,
.box .k-textbox:focus,
.box textarea:hover,
.box textarea:active,
.box textarea:focus {
    border-color: #cad0d6;
    background: #fff;
    color: #333;
    box-shadow: none;
}

.box.demo-description p {
    line-height: 1.5em;
    max-width: 1000px;
    padding-bottom: 1em;
}

.box.demo-description p:last-child {
    padding-bottom: 0;
}

.box.demo-description ul,
.box.demo-description ul li {
    list-style: disc inside;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    max-width: 1000px;
}

.box.demo-description ol,
.box.demo-description ol li {
    list-style: decimal inside;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    max-width: 1000px;
}

.box.demo-description ul,
.box.demo-description ol {
    margin: 1em;
    padding: 0;
}

.demo-hint {
    line-height: 22px;
    color: #aaa;
    font-style: italic;
    font-size: .9em;
    padding-top: 1em;
}

.responsive-message {
    font-size: 17px;
    display: none;
    margin: 4em auto;
    padding: 2.5em;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #ffda3f;
    color: #000;
}

.responsive-message:before {
    content: "This demo requires browser or device screen width to be equal or greater than 1024px.";
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1023px) {
  .page {
    max-width:100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px;
    background: #fff;
    border: 0;
  }
  
  .hidden-on-narrow {
    display: none !important;
  }
  .responsive-message {
    display: block;
  }
}
            div.console div {
                height: auto;
            }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <base href="https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/remote-data-binding">
    <style>html { font-size: 14px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }</style>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.3.1023/styles/kendo.default-v2.min.css" />

    <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.3.1023/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.3.1023/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
    

</head>
<body>

        <div id="example">
            <div id="grid"></div>

            <div class="box wide">
                <h4>Console log</h4>
                <div class="console"></div>
            </div>
        </div>



</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Problem seems to be by design and it will not be changed in the near future.

> We are considering improvements in dataSource requests. The current
>   state is with two calls because we use the first one to reset the
>   state of the datasource and the second one to apply the sorting.

Source: https://github.com/telerik/kendo-ui-core/issues/5462#issuecomment-563259073

Comment: Is there any patch/update for this issue ? Did kendo fix this ?

Comment: Well not as far as I know. The issue is still open.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how to prevent it.

Deep in kendo.all.js, in the FilterMenu widget filter method, is where the doubling appears to be happening:

```
            filter: function (expression) {
                var filters = this._stripFilters(expression.filters);
                if (filters.length && this.trigger('change', {
                        filter: {
                            logic: expression.logic,
                            filters: filters
                        },
                        field: this.field
                    })) {
                    return;
                }
                expression = this._merge(expression);
                if (expression.filters.length) {
                    this.dataSource.filter(expression);
                }
            },
```

This first time after a scroll that causes a data page to be loaded, a UI filtering will cause:

- `this.trigger('change',` to issue the request causing the first `dataBound`, and
- `this.dataSource.filter(expression);` to issue the request causing the second `dataBound`

Looking at the debugger network tab you will see the framework issues two `GET` requests. (I changed my page size to 8 so the URL parameters have `top=8`):

- `https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/Northwind.svc/Orders?$callback=jQuery1123011816937403352101_1583588644905&%24inlinecount=allpages&%24format=json&%24top=8`
- `https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/Northwind.svc/Orders?$callback=jQuery1123011816937403352101_1583588644905&%24inlinecount=allpages&%24format=json&%24top=8&%24filter=startswith(ShipName%2C%27h%27)`

Best responses would likely come from [Progress forums](https://www.telerik.com/forums).  You might need to be registered or licensed to post new questions there.

Comment: Thank you for your effort and answer. In the meantime I have found an answer from the Telerik team regarding this problem. Look at the accepted answer.